# CNN for feature array in python

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have an array data which has 5000 row(images) and 58 columns(features). And the array is CSV format. How can i classify with CNN?

I was trying this following code, but i got error. what is wrong?

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution1D, MaxPooling2D
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('/home/mahfuz/Documents/AllFeatures.csv')
data.head()
data.iloc[3,1:].values
df_x = data.iloc[:,1:].values
y = data.iloc[:,1].values
df_x = np.array(df_x)
df_y = np.array(y)
df_y
df_y.shape
df_x.shape
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_x,df_y,test_size=0.2,random_state=4)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(32, (3, 3), input_shape= ( 32, 32, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer = 'adadelta', metrices = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
model.evaluate(x_test,y_test)
```

Comment: See this :https://www.kaggle.com/jacklinggu/keras-mlp-cnn-test-for-text-classification

Comment: You have to reshape the data.

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask you what is the error?
First, Your data shape in the model is (32,32,3) on Conv1D, check it. 
Your images shape is (32, 32, 3) or you have data with shape (5000, 58) ?